# How can I estimate the uncertainty/probability of a single prediction (e.g., from a regression)?

Tags: regression, probability, uncertainty

I would like to create a statistical model (e.g., multiple linear regression) that  i can apply to new data to get a prediction of an outcome; as well as an probability/likelyhood estimate on the (un)certainty of that specific/single prediction.

If I understand it correctly, Neyman-Pearson (frequentist) statistics cannot say anything about the probability of a single prediction/event/hypothesis; whereas the Baysian approach can, right?

So, instead of using a standard multiple regression do I need to use a Baysian counterpart (and in that case which one, and what "uncertainanty estimate" is appropriate)?

I am particularly interested in this for categorical predictions. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Frequentist analysis can be performed with 1 sample. That’s not what is meant when people say frequentist notion of probability cannot be applied to unique events

Comment: Well frequentist analysis give a p-value based on P(Data|Hypothesis); whereas baysian gives P(Hypothesis|Data), right?

Comment: No. In the former we consider p(data at least as extreme as that observed|hypothesis)

Comment: So with frequentist analysis I can't apply it on a single event and say I can be X% certain this categorical prediction is correct, or?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#Regression_analysis .